# Use $lookup by referring to multiple values in the parent document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, lookup

I was trying out the new `$lookup` `pipeline` feature available in MongoDb 3.5.8 and wondering how to refer fields in the parent document from the `pipeline`.

I was trying to compare two fields in the parent document against two fields in the looked up document . Not sure how to do this `{$eq : ['$input_doc.field1', '$field1'] }`.

```
 db.input_doc.aggregate([
        {
          $lookup:
            {
              from: "foreign_doc",
              pipeline: [
                            { $project: { 'matched': { $and : [ 
                                { $eq : ["$input_doc.field1", "$field1"] }, 
                                { $eq : ["$input_doc.field2", "$field2"] } 
                                          ]} },
                            { $match : { 'matched' : true } }
              ],
              as: "as_doc"
            }
       }
    ])
```

Thanks

Comment: `pipeline` is intended for retrieving "non related data". if you have a relational field then use `localField` and `foreignField` instead. Of course if you want a logical comparison on all the results from the data then you would compare the array "after" the `$lookup` operation creates the array. You do NOT use this for related joins. See [DOCS-10298](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-10298).

Comment: @Neil Lunn Thanks for the info. I am trying to join by multiple fields between local and foreign doc as mentioned here [SERVER-21913](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-21913)

Comment: As mentioned in the ticket, it is open and unresolved, so not a feature yet. It looks like you really want a simple `$lookup` using `foreignKey` here. Edit your question to show what you are expecting as a result with both the local and foreign document. There are other ways to do what I think you want here. But show the case to make it clear.

Comment: Thanks Neil. In that case, what I am trying to do is not yet supported. The combination of the comments in that ticket led me to believe that the pipeline feature was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really clear what you mean here, you might possibly mean using `let` with the new `pipeline` option, but it's also likely you mean a completely different case.

The `pipeline` operation is generally intended for "non-correlated" data retrieval, which is useful in various use cases. This is as opposed to "correlated" data where the `localField` and `foreignField` can be applied to "join" between two collections.

As mentioned, this is covered in [DOCS-10298](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-10298)

Best demonstrated as an example. Take creation of these collections:

```
db.related.insert([
  { "a": 1, "b": 2 },
  { "a": 2, "b": 2 },
  { "a": 3, "b": 3 }
])

db.parent.insert({
  "name": "test",
  "b": 2
})
```

I can use the `pipeline` and `let` statements here to test a logical condition on the items of the other collection like so:

```
db.parent.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "related",
    "let": {
      "b": "$b"      
    },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$addFields": {
        "matched": { "$eq": [ "$$b", "$b" ] }
      }}
    ],
    "as": "results"
  }}
])
```

Which will give the result:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("595332c28965d862ce61f451"),
        "name" : "test",
        "b" : 2,
        "results" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59532b028965d862ce61f44d"),
                        "a" : 1,
                        "b" : 2,
                        "matched" : true
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59532b028965d862ce61f44e"),
                        "a" : 2,
                        "b" : 2,
                        "matched" : true
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59532b028965d862ce61f44f"),
                        "a" : 3,
                        "b" : 3,
                        "matched" : false
                }
        ]
}
```

That shows the condition was tested against the declared variable in `let` from the parent document against those from the related collection tested in the `pipeline` supplied.

This allows you to also use a "logical" filter such as [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/):

```
db.parent.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "related",
    "let": {
      "b": "$b"      
    },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$redact": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": { "$eq": [ "$$b", "$b" ] },
          "then": "$$KEEP",
          "else": "$$PRUNE"
        }
      }}
    ],
    "as": "results"
  }}
])
```

Which returns:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("595332c28965d862ce61f451"),
        "name" : "test",
        "b" : 2,
        "results" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59532b028965d862ce61f44d"),
                        "a" : 1,
                        "b" : 2
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("59532b028965d862ce61f44e"),
                        "a" : 2,
                        "b" : 2
                }
        ]
}
```

But of course, this is already covered with the existing functionality introduced in MongoDB 3.2 with the normal "correlated" options:

```
db.parent.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "related",
    "localField": "b",
    "foreignField": "b",
    "as": "results"
  }}
])
```

With the same results as above.

Of course if you want "additional conditions", then it's actually most efficient to write using [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/):

```
db.parent.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "related",
    "localField": "b",
    "foreignField": "b",
    "as": "results"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$results" },
  { "$match": { "results.a": 1  } }
])
```

This is because the aggregation pipeline options for the following stages after [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) are actually "hoisted" into the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) operation itself. Demonstrated in the "explain" output:

```
    {
            "$lookup" : {
                    "from" : "related",
                    "as" : "results",
                    "localField" : "b",
                    "foreignField" : "b",
                    "unwinding" : {
                            "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : false
                    },
                    "matching" : {
                            "a" : {
                                    "$eq" : 1
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
```

This shows the options of "unwinding" and "matching" have actually been applied within the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/). As yet you cannot just write that directly, but the pipeline combination applies this behavior.

This is in fact to essentially deal with the BSON Limit not being broken as a result of creating an array with entries that would exceed the 16MB cap.

In short, in most cases you generally want the existing behavior and do not need the new options. Yet.

Comment: Thank you Neil. Using `let` is what I need. I end up using `let` to define two variables (two keys) and then use them in the `pipeline` to compare with two fields in the joined collection. Also, just wondering what is the difference when using  `$project` in the place of `$addFields`. It gives me the same result.

Comment: @KinCheung Well they are different. `$addFields` actually "adds fields" to the existing document, much like I demonstrate in the answer if you look carefully. I'm still not convinced you "really" need this for your case, and you are probably better off using the same sort of think I demonstrate at the end, since something like `$redact` cannot use an index. The final form "can".